# Parse DEFAULT parameter of a ddl statement using ddlparse

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a ddl statement using ddlparse. I am able to parse every field except Default parameter. I followed the below link. 
*https://github.com/shinichi-takii/ddlparse*

Below is the ddl which i am trying to parse.

```
sample_ddl = """
CREATE TABLE My_Schema.Sample_Table (
  Id integer PRIMARY KEY ,
  Name varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'BASANT',
  Total bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  Avg decimal(5,1) NOT NULL,
  Created_At date, -- Oracle 'DATE' -> BigQuery 'DATETIME'
  UNIQUE (NAME)
);
"""
```

I can extract all information except DEFAULT parameter with below code :

```
for col in table.columns.values():
    col_info = []
    col_info.append("name = {}".format(col.name))
    col_info.append("data_type = {}".format(col.data_type))
    col_info.append("length = {}".format(col.length))
    col_info.append("precision(=length) = {}".format(col.precision))
    col_info.append("scale = {}".format(col.scale))
    col_info.append("constraint = {}".format(col.constraint))
    col_info.append("not_null = {}".format(col.not_null))
    col_info.append("PK = {}".format(col.primary_key))
    col_info.append("unique = {}".format(col.unique))
    col_info.append("bq_legacy_data_type = {}".format(col.bigquery_legacy_data_type))
    col_info.append("bq_standard_data_type = {}".format(col.bigquery_standard_data_type))
    col_info.append("comment = '{}'".format(col.comment))
    col_info.append("description(=comment) = '{}'".format(col.description))
    col_info.append("BQ {}".format(col.to_bigquery_field()))
    print(" : ".join(col_info))
```

Can anyone help me how to get the value for Default parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Added supports to get the Default attribute in `ddlparse` [v1.7.0](https://github.com/shinichi-takii/ddlparse/releases/tag/v1.7.0).

```py
for col in table.columns.values():
    col_info = {}

    col_info["default"] = col.default

    print(json.dumps(col_info, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

The default constraint of your `PRIMARY KEY` does not make many sense. In the context of `SQL Server` you can create the following default constraint but it will not work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Sample_Table

CREATE TABLE dbo.Sample_Table (
  Id integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 'BASANT',
  Name varchar(100) NOT NULL, --COMMENT 'User name',

);

INSERT INTO dbo.Sample_Table (Name)
VALUES ('x')
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'BASANT' to data type int.

Why? Because you can't set default value `string` to integer column.

And event if you said it to be number:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Sample_Table

CREATE TABLE dbo.Sample_Table (
  Id integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 1,
  Name varchar(100) NOT NULL, --COMMENT 'User name',

);

INSERT INTO dbo.Sample_Table (Name)
VALUES ('x');

INSERT INTO dbo.Sample_Table (Name)
VALUES ('x');
```

It will work only the first time, the second you will get:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 23 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK__Sample_T__3214EC0759729E5E'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'dbo.Sample_Table'. The duplicate key value is (1).

because the primary key value must be unique. You may be looking for something like this:

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Comment: Sorry the example was wrong. Let's take the below example.

Comment: sample_ddl = """
CREATE TABLE My_Schema.Sample_Table (
  Id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'Basant',
  Total bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  Avg decimal(5,1) NOT NULL,
  Created_At date, -- Oracle 'DATE' -> BigQuery 'DATETIME'
  UNIQUE (NAME)
);

Comment: Actually  i am trying to write a 'Alter table add column' command from the create table ddl. These are existing table. If someone wants to add a new column in the existing table, they are giving me the create table ddl. From this create table ddl, i am finding out the new column and creating a ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN ddl